# Javascript audio controls autoplay play pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a audio loop on my app and I want it to autoplay and toggle icon between play and pause. but not toggling between pause and play

**JS**

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'bglaughs.mp3');

audioElement.play();

audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
}, true);

if(audioElement.paused && audioElement.currentTime > 0 && !audioElement.ended) {
  $(document).on('click', '.play', function() {
          audioElement.play();
      $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
      $('a .fa-volume-off').removeClass('fa-volume-off').addClass('fa-volume-up');
  });

} else {
  $(document).on('click', '.pause', function() {
          audioElement.pause();
      $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
      $('a .fa-volume-up').removeClass('fa-volume-up').addClass('fa-volume-off');
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="music" style="color:black" class="play"><i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the autoplay and toggling working however initially It takes 2 clicks to stop the audio and then toggling resumes as normal afterwards. Any help as to why it is doing that?

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'bglaughs.mp3');

audioElement.load();
audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
  audioElement.play();
}, true);

audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
}, true);


  $(document).on('click', '.play', function() {
          audioElement.play();
      $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
      $('a .fa-volume-off').removeClass('fa-volume-off').addClass('fa-volume-up');
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.pause', function() {
          audioElement.pause();
      $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
      $('a .fa-volume-up').removeClass('fa-volume-up').addClass('fa-volume-off');
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the audio **IS PLAYING** on load...

Just set the anchor's onload class to pause.
And your code is correct.

```
<a href="#" id="music" style="color:black" class="pause">
```

[**Working CodePen here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LyZrjE?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can handle this with less code:

```
audioElement = new Audio('bglaughs.mp3');
audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
  audioElement.play();
}, false);
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
}, false);

$('#music').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var volIcon = $(this).find('i');
    volIcon.toggleClass('fa-volume-up fa-volume-off');
    if (volIcon.hasClass('fa-volume-off')) {
        audioElement.pause();
    } else {
        audioElement.play();
    }
});
```